# how to solve numpy data type change problem?

Tags: python, numpy

I meet a strange problem when I want to change the data type in numpy, for 1D can be changed, but 2D can not. Could give me some idea why this situation happen? 
Example:

```
a = np.array([['20101003', '', '20101003'], ['1.2', '', '2.3']])
b = np.array(['20101003', '', '20101003'])

def to_date(x):
    if x:
        return datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d').date()
    else:
        return None

a[0] = np.array(list(map(to_date, a[0])))
b = np.array(list(map(to_date, b)))
print(a[0], type(a[0]))
>>>['2010-10-' 'None' '2010-10-'] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(b, type(b))
>>>[datetime.date(2010, 10, 3) None datetime.date(2010, 10, 3)] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Why for b can succeed change the data type, but for a[0] can not.

Thanks

Comment: You are assigning it to the array of strings again. Try assigning to a new variable, then it works `a1 = np.array(list(map(to_date, a[0])))`
this returns, 
`array([datetime.date(2010, 10, 3), None, datetime.date(2010, 10, 3)],
      dtype=object)`

Comment: @Arihant Yes, this one work, but I want to know why 'assigning it to the array of strings again' can not work? You mean just replace the old str, so the length of str are same?

Comment: The numpy array can only contain single data type. Since it was initially string and contains string in other rows, it will consider any data as a string. You would have to assign it to a new array, if you are converting it into other data types.

Comment: You absolutely cannot change the dtype of a numpy array by assigning to an individual element, since the dtype is necessarily the same for all elements.  But you can certainly choose a new dtype when assigning a new array to a variable; whatever that variable might have held before is completely irrelevant.